# checkboxlist selectall using Knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist, I am trying to implement SelectAll/DeselectAll functionality.The items of the checkboxlist are being bound from the database.

This is how my checkboxlist looks

```
<div class="options" 
     data-bind="foreach: Factor,visible: true" style="display: none;">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class='roles' name='roles' 
            data-bind="attr: { value: Id }, 
                       checked:MyViewModel.MyData.MyCheckedValues" />
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

MyCheckedValues and Factor are observable arrays here.

This is how MyData looks

```
MyData: function () {
    var currentObject = this;
    currentObject.MyCheckedValues= ko.observableArray()
}

selectAll: function()
{
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(); 
    return true;
}
```

In the internet articles I found, a separate function is used where they declare an attribute called `IsSelected` and set it to false initially etc and then loop through it.
But I dont have any separate function related to this.

Can you help me implementing select/deselect all?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ko.computed for selectAll and Deselect.

html:-

```
 <span data-bind="text: selectAll()?'Deselect All':'Select All'"></span><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectAll" />
 <div class="options" data-bind="foreach: Factor,visible: true" style="display: none;">
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class='roles' name='roles' data-bind="attr: { value: id },checked:isSelected" /> <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

ViewModel:-

```
 function Factor(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
 }
function viewModel() {
  var currentObject = this;
  currentObject.Factor = ko.observableArray([new Factor(1, "Jack"), new Factor(2, "John")]);

  currentObject.selectAll = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var item = ko.utils.arrayFirst(currentObject.Factor(), function (i) {
            return !i.isSelected();
        });
        return item == null;
    },
    write: function (value) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(currentObject.Factor(), function (i) {
            i.isSelected(value);
        });
    }
  });
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EUP86/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see your full model and am a bit confused by your bindings, I've made a quick example for you that you should be able to modify for your use.

Markup:

```
<button data-bind="click: selectAllCheckboxes">Select all</button>
<button data-bind="click: deselectAllCheckboxes">Deselect all</button>
<ul data-bind="foreach: data">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: Id, checked: $parent.selectedCheckboxes">
            <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the JS:

```
var myViewModel = function () {
    this.data = ko.observableArray( [
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Example 1' },
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Example 2' },
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Example 3' },
        { Id: 4, Name: 'Example 4' },
        { Id: 5, Name: 'Example 5' }
    ] );

    this.selectedCheckboxes = ko.observableArray();

    this.selectAllCheckboxes = function () {
        var selectedCheckboxesArray = this.selectedCheckboxes();
        selectedCheckboxesArray.length = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach( this.data(), function ( data ) {
            selectedCheckboxesArray.push( '' + data.Id );
        } );
        this.selectedCheckboxes.valueHasMutated();
    };

    this.deselectAllCheckboxes = function () {
        this.selectedCheckboxes().length = 0;
        this.selectedCheckboxes.valueHasMutated();
    };
};

ko.applyBindings( new myViewModel() );
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4VGGd/